# CS50 PSET3 Tideman - I keep getting an error (lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates a cycle)

Tags: c, cs50

I am new to coding and cannot for the life of me figure out why I keep getting this error. I know that there are simpler solutions to the lock_pairs function using recursion, but this is what I came up myself and wanted to follow through with it. Any help is appreciated!

```
// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        int k = pairs[i].loser;
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (locked[k][j] == true && j == pairs[i].winner)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (locked[k][j] == true)
            {
                k = j;
                j = -1;
            }
            if (j == (candidate_count - 1) && locked[k][j] == false)
            {
                locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        int false_number = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (locked[j][i] == false)
            {
                false_number++;
                if (false_number == candidate_count)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, you only need to check for a cycle during the last iteration. Using an array of the number of candidates you can tract the number of candidates locked and if there is only a single candidate unlocked, and an arrow would lock the candidate edge -- don't lock the edge. [Example - Tideman](https://paste.opensuse.org/2800613)

Comment: Assuming that anyone here might know what your code is about, is a bit optimistic. You should always describe, what you want to do and what part of it fails. Tests at CS50 should include some detail about the test. Inspect the result carefully and provide any available information about the test case that failed.